# Difference between the values of a variable

Tags: c#, casting

I wrote a code for checking typecasting in C#. The following code:

```
using System;
class Convert{
    public static void Main(){
        double a=14.25,b=26.12;
        var z=(int)(a*b);
        Console.WriteLine("z= "+z);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Gave output:

```
z=372
```

But when i modified the code a bit then i got a big difference between the value of z earlier and after modification.

```
using System;
    class Convert{
        public static void Main(){
            double a=14.25,b=26.12;
            var z=(int)a*b;  // Modified part
            Console.WriteLine("z= "+z);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
```

Gave output:

```
z=365.68
```

I don't understand that why is there so much difference after removing the brackets from the original code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without the outer parentheses, the `(int)` cast applies to `a` only.
Therefore, you end up multiplying a truncated integer by a normal double, and type inference turns `var` into `double`.

With the parentheses, the cast applies to the result of the multiplication. Therefore, the entire result gets truncated, and type inference turns `var` into `int`.

---

Thus, changing `var` to `double` would have no effect on either example.  (in the second case, it would assign the truncated `int` to a `double` variable)

Changing `var` to `int` would turn the second example into a compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

brackets set prioryty

```
var z=(int)(a*b);//(a*b) cast to int
var z=(int)a*b;//a cast to int and myltiply with b
```

Answer (score 0):

the priority of conversation operation `()` is bigger than multiply priority.
in first case you have:

```
double tmp = a*b;
int z = (int)tmp;
```

and in second:

```
int tmp = (int)a;
double z = tmp * b;
```

Answer (score 0):

in the line

```
var z=(int)a*b;
```

a is being converted into an int before it is being multiplied. So it is going to be 14*26.12. Where in the 2nd case, you are multiplying a*b and converting the result into an int afterward.